# Should anonymous class object set to null onDestroy?

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks, anonymous-class

I heard that [the Anonymous Classes can leak memory](http://blog.nimbledroid.com/2016/05/23/memory-leaks.html).

> Similarly, Anonymous Classes will also maintain a reference to the class that they were declared inside. Therefore a leak can occur if you declare and instantiate an AsyncTask anonymously inside your Activity. If it continues to perform background work after the Activity has been destroyed, the reference to the Activity will persist and it won’t be garbage collected until after the background task completes.

Should anonymous class object set to null onDestroy to prevent memory leaks? Here are some pieces of my code.

```
public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ApiHandler registerHandler = null;
    private static final int SERVICE_REQUEST_REGISTER = 243;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        useApiService();
        initApiHandler();
    }

    protected void useApiService() {
        apiService = ApiClient.getClient(getApplicationContext()).create(ApiInterface.class);
    }

    private void initApiHandler() {
        registerHandler = new ApiHandler(this, SERVICE_REQUEST_REGISTER) {
            @Override
            protected String successStatusCode() {
                return "802";
            }

            @Override
            protected String secretKey() {
                return getDefaultKey();
            }

            @Override
            protected boolean isExchangeSecretKey() {
                return false;
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        registerHandler = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are making an AsyncTask, and you know the activity will be destroyed or might be destroyed in the process, then call AsyncTask.cancel()  inside of onDestroy() before the super.onDestroy() ... Also, inside of your AsyncTask class, inside of onCancel() make sure that you clear everything there

Comment: Nulling references is less useful than people usually think, usually unnecessary. Prevention is better than a cure. Instead of nulling references, don't do GC's job, scope your references carefully. Don't use inner classes to hold references to containing classes' instances inappropriately. If you coordinate object lifetimes properly you won't need kludgey hacks to coöpt memory management.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually garbage colector do it for you.

What the piece of text you pasted says is if the Anonymous class you are creating start a new AsyncTask, the main class where you created it will never be destroyed...

in other words while there is one Anonymous class running tasks onDestroy is never called on main class